# Cannot access puma http site on port 3000

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, puma

I have deployed a Ruby application into AWS Ubuntu 18.4 using mina. I have used Puma as http server and Puma started on port 3000 successfully but not able to access the site.

**puma.Servive**

```
[Unit]
Description=Puma HTTP Server
After=network.target

# Uncomment for socket activation (see below)
# Requires=puma.socket

[Service]
Type=simple

User=ubuntu

WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/appname/current

# Helpful for debugging socket activation, etc.
Environment=PUMA_DEBUG=1

ExecStart=/bin/bash -lc 'RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec puma  -C /home/ubuntu/appname/current/config/puma.rb'

Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**Puma service status is as follows:-**
[image]

But when I try to curl http://0.0.0.0:3000 or http://127.0.0.1:3000 or http://localhost:3000, nothing happens. Even no error logs are generated. Though I can curl to port 80.

Once the issue is resolved I can proceed to integrate puma with nginx. Any suggestion is appreciated.

**EDIT-1**

NB: The curl oprations I tried were done AWS machine itself, not from outside.

**EDIT-2**
According to suggestion from **Casper** I checked and found that puma is listening to port 3000.

[image]

**EDIT-3**

When I try to curl no result comes up and for lynx got failure to connect with port 3000
[image]

Comment: You should use that machine's IP address: `http://<ip of my aws machine>:3000`.

Comment: I have not integrated puma with nginx yet, and no response for AWS piblic IP as well. NB: I edited my question.

Comment: `sudo netstat -tunlp` tells you all services listening on the host and which processes are attached to those ports. Please check the output to verify puma is listening.

Comment: Yes, puma is listening to port 3000, I have added ss, please have a look @Casper

Comment: What does "nothing happens" mean? Something always happens. Please describe exactly what happens.

Comment: Nothing means, when I try to curl no result comes up and for lynx got failure to connect with port 3000. Firewall is disabled on the machine. Let me check the logs from rails side, thank you for your time.

Comment: You have a HTTP connection being converted to HTTPS. There is your problem. Your system is probably not set up for HTTPS.

Comment: Exactly, I have set config.force_ssl=false for production and it's working now.